# I had better go, I should go, I have to go

Tags: phrases, auxiliary-verbs

Could anyone tell me what these mean, and on what occasions it is suitable to say them?

1. *I had better go*
2. *I should go*
3. *I have to go.*

Comment: #3, when you have to do #1 really bad.

Comment: re 1 vs 2: " 'Had better' is similar to 'should but' not exactly the same... With 'had better', there is always a danger or a problem if you don't follow the advice." - English Grammar in Use, 3rd ed., Murphy, p.70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two mean the same thing, that going would be a wise course of action for the speaker. The third sentence means that the speaker must go (i.e., it is a requirement).